# Ajax passing php variable to javascript function as an argument

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have three tables in my database: `Person (id, name, last_name), System (id, name), PersonInSystem(id, person_id, system_id)`. The last one is used to link a person with a system.

I use `<select>` to display every person from my DB like this

```
echo '<option value="'.$queryResult["id"].'">'.$queryResult["name"].' '.$queryResult["last_name].'</option>';
```

I use Ajax to get the id and to send a query `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE id = ID_FROM_SELECT`. Then, I display the data like this (I can't copy the code, so I have to rewrite it from head, I will use pseudo PHP + HTML), and the main purpose of it is to edit a chosen person:

```
<form>
Name: <input type="text" value="'.$nameFromDB.'" name="name">
Last name: <input type="text" value="'.$lastNameFromDB.'" name="lastname">
System: while () { // if one person is assigned to many systems, I will display them all in separate selects
            <select><option value="'.$systemAssignedToPerson.'">'.$systemAssignedToPerson.'</option>
            while () {
            // display every system except for the one listed above
            }
            </select><img src="drop.gif" onclick="deleteSystem(document.getElementById(\"system\").value)"><input type="hidden" id="system" value="'.$systemAssignedToPerson.'"> 
        }

<input type-"submit" value="Edit" name="editPerson">
</form>
```

Now if I want to unassign a person from given system, I would like to click the drop.gif image and trigger `deleteSystem(value)` function, which will send query `DELETE FROM PersonInSystem WHERE system_id = SYSTEM_ID_SENT and person_id = PERSON_ID_SENT`, but I can't pass the value and I don't have really idea how to do it (I'm new with Ajax).

I can store person's id in a session variable, but I don't know how to send system id, and also I don't want to sent the data to another page.

Also I would like to refresh the page with changed system assignment (the same person should be displayed).

Comment: i wanted to give you an answer, but i already found some basic problems in your code. you putting out a static `id` within your `PHP` while loop: `<input type="hidden" id="system" value="'.$systemAssignedToPerson.'">`. so your html will be invalid (every id can only appear once per page) and your javascript can't distinguish between the different values of your hidden field (since all of them got the same "id").

Answer (score 3):

I think you need native javascript function call to the server

```
function deleteSystem(value){  
    var deleteflag=confirm("Are you sure to delete?!!");
      if(deleteflag){
        //setup your request to the server
         window.location='delete.php?SYSTEM_ID_SENT='+value

       }

    }
```

In your delete.php file you can get the SYSTEM_ID_SENT in this way

```
 $id=$_GET['SYSTEM_ID_SENT'];
 $personid=$_SESSION['your session variable name'];
// run your delete query
 $delqry=mysql_query("");
 if($delqry){
      //redirect to the page you want
      header('location:yourpage.php');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the code as below.
It should work

```
<img src="drop.gif" onclick="deleteSystem('<?php echo $systemAssignedToPerson;?>')">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your deleteSystem JavaScript function needs to send the following kind of request to the server:

(Example: Handler file for unassign)

```
"unassign.php?systemId=459&personId=300"
```

(Example: Generic handler file)

```
"handler.php?systemId=459&personId=300&action=unassign"
```

In unassign.php:

```
$systemId = $_GET["systemID"];
$personId = $_GET["personID"];
/* Your SQL stuff here - 
statement something like 
DELETE FROM PersonInSystem WHERE person_id = "$personId" AND system_id = "$systemId" */
```

Improvements:
* Use a javascript library like Prototype (oldschool, lightweight) or jQuery (more heavy) for handling the Ajax stuff
* Use $_POST and post variables instead of $_GET
* Use a library for properly quoting your SQL
* Care about html special characters and proper input validation/filtering